# CGAffineTransform issue unable to manage scale ios

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I have `UIView` with two subView's inside it.

When I apply a `CGAffineTransform` to zoom the parent view I want only the parent to get zoomed but not its subViews.

If there any way to do this please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to apply the inverse transform to each subview. It can be calculated by the inverse of the scale (`1.0 / scale`) or [CGAffineTransformInvert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455264-cgaffinetransforminvert) but this is error-prone.

Another solution is to move the subviews outside of the zoomed view to the parent view such that the subviews become siblings of the zoomed view.